# Aurelia validation not working for derived classes

Tags: aurelia

I have the following scenario in typescript 1.6 and the latest aurelia:

```
import {ensure, Validation} from "aurelia-validation";
import {ValidationGroup} from "aurelia-validation";

@inject(Validation)
export class BaseClass {

  validation: ValidationGroup;

  @ensure(function (it) { it.isNotEmpty().hasLengthBetween(3, 10) })
  firstName: string;

  constructor(validation: Validation) {
    this.validation = validation.on(this, null);
  }
}

@inject(Validation)
export class DerivedClass extends BaseClass {

  @ensure(function (it) { it.isNotEmpty().hasLengthBetween(3, 10) })
  lastName: string;

  constructor(validation: Validation) {
    super(validation);
  }

  submit() {
    this.validation.validate().then((value) => { /* */ });
  }
}
```

The problem is that, when I submit the form data in the view from `derived-class.html` only the `lastName` property gets validated, and the `firstName` property isn't even listed in the validation group.

Comment: the official word on this is don't derive classes. that doesn't really work for me either, though.

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis I've also opened an [issue](https://github.com/aurelia/validation/issues/148) on the validation repo. I think the problem comes from using aurelia/metadata to extract class' properties.

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis [Here](https://github.com/aurelia/validation/commit/71e5d236d0100aa8082d32c45566b5ddef3fd2b5#diff-e574062f805679ea3a2402db238a6d04L26) you can see the difference which I think breaks this functionality.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this was asked about an early alpha preview that is no longer even possible to use.